# SQL Server Linked with Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I am working on SQL Server for a long time, recently I decided to learn also Oracle and finally connect them together.

So my configuration now is:

- SQL SERVER 2016
- SQL MANAGEMENT STUDIO 16.5
- ORACLE 12C
- SQL DEVELOPER 4.1
- ORACLE CLIENT 32x&64x

I created a linked server in SQL Server with OraOLEDB provider to my SID of Oracle Database.

The problem is that, when linked server **security context** is using **HR** account from PDB I am able to browse the tables in the Object Explorer.
In the other hand, when the **security context** is using a **test user** account from CDB which I created then tables node in Object Explorer says "expanding..." and never loads the tables.

I tried also to give all privileges to my test user through SYS AS DBA but no luck. In addition, I tried to give all privileges to the test user through hr account again no luck.

Finally, I noticed that users from PDB database can be used for Linked Server by using Client Tools, but this is not an option for CDB users, so is there anything that should do in order to connect with CDB users?

Comment: If I understood you. Everything works fine when in linked server Security settings you choose *'Be made using this security context'* with oracle db user **HR**. When you switch to *'Be made using the login's current security context'* it doesn't work. 

Well it's expected because os authentication in Oracle requires either Advanced Securiti configuration or if Oracle DB is run on Windows configuration of windows authentication.

Comment: I dont think that is the authentication of OS because both users are oracle users. Test user is from CDB and the hr is from PDB database.